# Cliente enviando String[] ao invés de BigDecimal para servidor ao alterar

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring, jsp

Quando é um **novo registro** funciona **tranquilamente**, **o problema** está na **alteração**.

Possuo um objeto **A** que é o mestre, outro objeto **B** que é um `ArrayList` e detalhe do mestre **A** e por último, um objeto **C** que é `ArrayList` e detalhe do objeto **B**.

Quando envio as informações para o servidor e o `index` do objeto **B** **é igual** a 0 e o detalhe que é o objeto **C** não está nulo funciona corretamente sem reclamar para converter `String[]` para `BigDecimal`.

Porém quando envio para o servidor as informações e o `index` do objeto **B** **é maior** que 0 e o detalhe que é o objeto **C** não está nulo é acusado que está tentando converter `String[]` para `BigDecimal` e retorna erro.

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
>   Field error in object 'A' on field 'B[1].C[0].atributo': rejected value [190.67,190.67]; ...(Outros erros não listados, porém não é diferente desse que ocorreu já que se trata de um detalhe).

Como está definido o elemento no **JSP** que preencho utilizando AngularJS quando o usuário clicar para gerar um novo item no detalhe **C**:

```
name='B[{{B.index}}].C[{{C.index}}].atributo'
```

Como está no model:

```
@Column(name = "ATRIBUTO")
@NotNull(message = "{validate.required.atributo}")
@NumberFormat(pattern = "0.00")
private BigDecimal atributo;
```

Prints de como está no JavaScript no evento **submit** do **form**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro que retorna para o usuário na camada de cliente:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] to required type java.math.BigDecimal for property B[1].C[0].atributo; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Alguma solução para esse problema? Aparentemente acredito eu que a definição no atributo **name** para gerar corretamente os objetos na camada do servidor está correta, ainda mais que é salva no banco de dados quando é um novo registro, o problema ocorre quando entramos alterando e quando o objeto **B** irá possuir o atributo **C** que não vai ser nulo, está em um index maior que 0 ocasionando o aparecimento de um vetor de String no atributo como vocês perceberam pela mensagem de erro já que parece que foi multiplicado por tantos elementos que existem no detalhe **B**.

A questão é, como arrumar isso sendo que aparentemente está correto?

Comment: Ao que parece o angular está transformando um número para string e ai ocorre o erro. Veja se consegue imprimir os dados antes de enviá-los para o servidor.

Comment: O valor rejeitado é realmente uma string inválida: `'190.67,190.67'` (já que você definiu na interface que o formato esperado é string[]). O correto seria um retorno como elementos individualizados - `['190.67','190.67']`.

Comment: Coloquei um alert em um evento antes de dar submit no form em um dos elementos do terceiro detalhe, ou seja, o objeto **C** na alteração e retornou um valor númerico, não uma String. E o que espera no servidor é um elemento do tipo de BigDecimal, editei a pergunta colocando o model.

Comment: O primeiro valor que passa no vetor é o valor **antigo** e o segundo valor é o valor **novo** que deveria substituir o **antigo**.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu Erro:

*org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors Field error in object 'A' on field 'B[1].C[0].atributo': rejected value [190.67,190.67]; ...(Outros erros não listados, porém não é diferente desse que ocorreu já que se trata de um detalhe).*

O problema é que você está tratando seu vetor inteiro como uma string. Veja como você está enviando antes os valores deste seu vetor, fazendo a conversão unitária.

```
["190.67", "190.67", ...]
```